# $\mathbf{z} = \alpha \mathbf{x} + (1 - \alpha)\mathbf{y}$ is a solution of the system of equations $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ for any real $\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Paraphrasing, chapter 2.4 (Linear Dependence and Span), page 35 of *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, claims something like the following:

> If $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are solutions to the system of equations $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, then $\mathbf{z} = \alpha \mathbf{x} + (1 - \alpha)\mathbf{y}$ is also a solution for any real $\alpha$.

I don't recall ever seeing this claim when studying linear algebra, and I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to inform me of the theorem and proof, so that I may understand it.

Comment: By linearity, a linear transformation applied to a linear combination yields the linear combination of the transformation applied to the individual vectors.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the clarification. This comment is good with reference to José's proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that\begin{align}A\mathbf z&=A\bigl(\alpha\mathbf x+(1-\alpha)\mathbf y\bigr)\\&=\alpha A\mathbf x+(1-\alpha)A\mathbf y\\&=\bigl(\alpha+(1-\alpha)\bigr)\mathbf b\\&=\mathbf b.\end{align}

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thank you very much for the clarification.